# How to perform a clean install of High Sierra from USB without causing a loop?

Tags: install, high-sierra

I recently installed an SSD hard drive for my Mac Mini, and all went fine until I tried to do a clean installation of High Sierra via USB.

I've downloaded the installer to USB memory stick by following the steps described in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVkMvO60SAs
That is, configuring the pen through Terminal, etc, etc ...

Once formatted the new SSD in APSC format, from the Utilities menu of MacOs I click "install High Sierra". After several minutes of loading bars with apparent normality, finally it goes to a black screen with the apple and a load bar that never complete. After that, it comes back to the previous menu of MacOs Utilities as if nothing had happened. And so in loop again and again.

How can I proceed with the installation from here?

Comment: The question is, how can i install High Sierra without this loop?

Answer (score 1):

I had the identical issue on any old Mac I replace drive with SSD.

Workaround I got is to install Sierra and upgrade to High Sierra, but it takes ages.

A better solution: disk cannot be APFS, so erase with JHFS+ and it works fine.

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ …
```